# Use freemarker library in android

Tags: android, freemarker

I am trying to use freemarker library into my project but I am getting error while initializing Configuration object.

I further investigated the the issue and I found [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/freemarker/feature-requests/94/) link.
I have tried to apply patch given in above link but I could not apply it successfully.

Can someone having used Freemarker in Android please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem:**

Although Freemarker officially does not support Android, it published special *.jars for GAE to provide some support, and a lot of other Android solutions could successfully use Freemarker in their application (either rendering view/code, or just to evaluate some expressions).

**Cause:**

The root cause of the issue is that Freemarker would use a few things from `java.beans` package which is for some reason not included in Android core libraries.

According to a reply on Stackoverflow (*/questions/15065545/using-jars-that-use-java-beans-classes-introspector-beaninfo-or-propertydescri*), this is a disadvantage of Android, and to accomplish the task, we should “fork all 3th party jars from source and rewrite them so they don't use `java.beans.*` classes (possibly by replacing them for openbeans).”

**Solution:**

Find a substitution for `java.beans`, which can be changed, so it would work on Android. It can be `openbeans`, or `mad-robot` for example.

Even there is a patch existing for Freemarker, which is basically changing `java.beans` to `mad-robot` beans in its source code - you can find the patch and the related thread [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/freemarker/feature-requests/94/).

**Possible workarounds:**

- Applying the patch for Freemarker Android support
- Manually recompiling with `openbeans.jar`: code.google.com/p/openbeans/
- Manually recompiling with `mad-robot` beans: code.google.com/p/mad-robot/

Comment: I have been having this problem and switching to the GAE version solved it for me.  Thanks!