# Freemarker GAE on Android

Tags: android, freemarker

I'm trying to use Freemarker GAE on Android without success (same code runs on a PC). I found this 4 years old thread:

[use-freemarker-library-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929542/use-freemarker-library-in-android)

As described on the thread the problem relies on the fact that Android misses java.beans implementation. Did somebody manage to run it on Android? How?
What is the purpose of the GAE version of the library, it's this the branch meant to run on Android?

Thanks

Comment: GAE is for Google App Engine (server platform), not for Android.

Comment: The GAE version isn't specifically targeted at Android, but it will work.  I have been having this same issue and just got it working by switching to the GAE version.